# NDK Build failing

Tags: android, android-ndk, compiler-errors

Am new to working with ndk. Seeing some posts and googling around i found the way to compile my native files using NDK. I installed ndk r7c. However when i used the command ndk-build i got the following error:

```
/cygdrive/d/android-ndk-r7c-windows/android-ndk-r7c/ndk-build
/cygdrive/d/android-ndk-r7c-windows/android-ndk-r7c/ndk-build: line 40: dirname: command not found
/cygdrive/d/android-ndk-r7c-windows/android-ndk-r7c/ndk-build: line 78: uname: command not found
ERROR: Unknown host operating system:
```

My directory for the project was:

```
Haris Riaz@HarisRiaz-PC /cygdrive/d/reader-2/android/jni
```

Am unable to know the nature of the problem. Please help me whats this error about and how to solve it. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `Haris Riaz@HarisRiaz-PC` I can deduct that you are running on Linux. But according to `android-ndk-r7c-windows`, you are trying to run a windows version ow the NDK. And `ERROR: Unknown host operating system:` confirms this. Download Linux version of the NDK from [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) and you should be fine.

Comment: but am using cygwin on windows. How to cater that?? am not working in linux. would this version work fine for me? This haris riaz@harisriaz-pc is from the cygwin terminal!

Comment: You don't need cygwin to run NDK tools in windows. Just use windows shell `cmd`. There's a pretty detailed tutorial on running NDK in windows here: http://psrdotcom.blogspot.fr/2011/12/android-ndk-jni-windows-xp7-with-3264.html