# Android studio:import NDK project from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, android-ndk, android-studio

I exported project from Eclipse(windows) and imported it to android studio V 0.4.2(ubuntu).

 The project include working NDK library.

I get this error when try to run my app:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk'.
```

> NDK not configured

From others stackoverflow posts, I understand that it is an issue.

But get no workaround for this.
Should i proceed the development with eclipse for now, or is that the a lazy option ?

EDIT :
I run this command:

```
export NDK=~/Downloads/android-ndk-r9c
```

and then :

and then go to my app directory and run this:

```
 ndk-build
```

And i get this:

```
        yarinkos-u@yarinkosu-MSI-Notebook-EX600:~/AndroidStudioProjects/AndEngineEXperimental$ ndk-build
    /home/yarinkos-u/Downloads/android-ndk-r9c/ndk-build: 1: /home/yarinkos-u/Downloads/android-ndk-r9c/ndk-build: dirname: not found
    /home/yarinkos-u/Downloads/android-ndk-r9c/ndk-build: 132: /home/yarinkos-u/Downloads/android-ndk-r9c/ndk-build: uname: not found
ERROR: Unknown host operating system:
```

What i did wrong?
It seems that the script running,but i miss something there.

EDIT 2:

i mistakenly runing this also :

```
 export PATH=~/Downloads/android-ndk-r9c
```

so i get the error above.
If i running onlt this :

```
export NDK=~/Downloads/android-ndk-r9c
```

I get ndk-build not found error.

Comment: Mention Android Studio version in every question you ask related to AS because there are frequent updates and behavior different in each version. It will help answerer as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NDK Support is introduced from Android Studio 0.4.1 only, so make sure you are running AS 0.4.1 or above.

Android gradle plugin must be **0.7.+** in build.gradle file and also new NDK integration requires **NDK r9c** .

Lines from Developer tools blog under Release 0.4.1

> Supports importing NDK projects. If the imported project contains NDK
>   sources, these are imported into the jni/ source set of the project,
>   the module name is inferred from the Makefile and stored in the Gradle
>   file, and the ndk.dir property is defined in local.properties.

Check more about it here :

http://tools.android.com/recent

Comment: im using 0.4.2 android studio and i just dwonloaded the ndkr9c.do yu know how do install the ndk? im new to ubuntu too,not only for android studio

Comment: you just need to set environment path variable . Might be this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18508453/building-android-ndk-in-eclipse-in-ubuntu

Comment: `Unknown host operating system` It means you are working on linux but have downloaded the Windows version of NDK . Please download the correct version from here http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html

Comment: this is the file that i extract: android-ndk-r9c-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2. im runing ubuntu X64 and the script running.BTW,now when i try it again,i get ndk-build not found.frustrated

Comment: I found something related to this, check if this could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15180058/ndk-build-failing

Comment: i edit the question again.and tnx, i will try it.but it is very frustrated not to be able to running your project for days on ubuntu:/

Answer (score 0):

you need to download the NDK for your operatings system @ https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html once it's downloaded, install it it'll extract the contents to the correct file system it needs to be in it'll take some time, also make sure you are running the latest android studio. it worked for me. good luck.